# How to use gnocchi, aodh

Tags: openstack, heat

*Hi, 
I'm trying to make simple openstack loadbalancer with cpu_util, memory and disk usage. But I'm struggle with aodh, gnocchi api.*

---

1. I installed openstack with devstack(I posted local.conf file below ). But whenever I tried to matric/v1/matirc with admin token, it returns 503 internal error. I thought devstack configure everything to use gnocchi. Could you tell me what's I need to configure to use gnocchi api.

   ```
    
   [[local|localrc]]


   HOST_IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

   ADMIN_PASSWORD=devstack
   RABBIT_PASSWORD=devstack
   SERVICE_PASSWORD=devstack
   DATABASE_PASSWORD=devstack

   GIT_BASE=https://git.openstack.org/ 

   NOVA_BRANCH=stable/rocky
   NOVACLIENT_BRANCH=stable/rocky
   KEYSTONE_BRANCH=stable/rocky
   KEYSTONECLIENT_BRANCH=stable/rocky
   CINDER_BRANCH=stable/rocky
   NEUTRON_BRANCH=stable/rocky
   GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/rocky 

   enable_plugin heat https://git.openstack.org/openstack/heat stable/rocky

   enable_plugin heat-dashboard https://git.openstack.org/openstack/heat-dashboard stable/rocky
   enable_service h-eng h-api h-cfn h-api-cw heat-dashboard

   enable_plugin neutron-lbaas https://git.openstack.org/openstack/neutron-lbaas stable/rocky
   enable_plugin neutron-lbaas-dashboard https://git.openstack.org/openstack/neutron-lbaas-dashboard stable/rocky
   enable_plugin octavia https://git.openstack.org/openstack/octavia stable/rocky

   enable_service q-svc q-agt q-dhcp q-l3 q-meta
   enable_service q-lbaasv2 neutron-lbaas-dashboard
   enable_service octavia o-cw o-hk o-hm o-api

   enable_plugin ceilometer https://git.openstack.org/openstack/ceilometer.git stable/rocky

   CEILOMETER_BACKEND=gnocchi

   enable_plugin aodh https://git.openstack.org/openstack/aodh stable/rocky
   enable_plugin panko https://git.openstack.org/openstack/panko stable/rocky

   enable_service c-bak
   enable_service swift
   ```

---

2. What I want to do with gnocchi api was cheacking what kind of data it has. Because gnocchi doc only tells about cpu_util. I want to know what data gnocchi can collect and for collect that do i need to configure something?

---

3. with that information, I want to make loadbalancer using aodh and heat. On aodh api doc only show alarm with cpu_util. Can I give a alarm based on disk,memory and cpu usage.

---

4. On aodh api doc, It gets cpu_util data from gnocchi. when create alarm it gets a threshold number like 0.8. I thought gnocchi doesn't give a cpu_util value like that. where and how threshold calculated?

---

***It's my first question on stack-over-flow so I may have made lots of mistakes.***
**Thank you for reading it and I hope you have time to answer it.**